# Use firebase tokens to query an API in a client

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I used firebase authentication to secure my ASP.NET CORE api.

I actually store the users in the database my API uses. Note that in my database the google identifiers are the uids generated by the firebase authentication and that the classic identifiers (login + password) are generated in my API.

When the user connects with Google, the token is created in the client(Angular) so I send it to my API (of course I don't store it), I just check if the token is valid and if the id which is contained in the token corresponds to the identifier of one of the users which is stored in my database.

In my client, for google authentification:

```
async GoogleAuth() {
try {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    signInWithPopup(this.auth, this.provider).then(() => {
      this.auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        if (user) {
          user
            .getIdToken()
            .then((idToken) => {
              this.sendTokenUserGoogleToAPI(user, idToken)
                .then((data: any) => {
                  localStorage.setItem('token', data.token);
                  resolve(data);
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                  console.log("googleAuth : " + error)
                  reject(error);
                });
            })
            .catch(() => { });
        }
      });
    });
  });
} catch (e) { }
```

}

For the classic connection (login + password), the data is sent directly to my API and I create a personalized token with the user ID in my backend and I send the token to the client who generates a personalized token to from the token.

In my API, for classic authentication :

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("signin")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> SignIn([FromBody] UserLoginViewModel userModel)
    {
        var user = await _context.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u =>
            u.Login == userModel.Login && u.Password == userModel.Password);
        if (user == null)
        {
            _logger.LogWarning("Connection attempt failed.");
            return NotFound(new { message = "User or password invalid." });
        }
        if (user.IsLocked)
        {
            return new ObjectResult(new { message = "Your account has been blocked." }) { StatusCode = 403 };
        }
        var token = await FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance.CreateCustomTokenAsync(user.UserId);
        var login = user.Login;
        return Ok(new
        {
            login,
            token
        });
    }
```

In my client, when I receive the token from my API

```
signInWithCustomToken(getAuth(),token)
    .then((userCredential) => {
      const user = userCredential.user;
      console.log(token)
        user!.getIdToken(true).then((idToken) => {
          localStorage.setItem('token', idToken)
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
        })
    })
```

So I'm guessing I shouldn't generate the token in my backend and only return the id to generate the token in the client? I regenerate the token in my client so that the user can access the chat

With my client, is it better that I get the token by querying firebase each time or is it better that I store this token locally to be able to use it in my requests?

For the moment, I store it locally but I think that it can be problematic if the token changes or if an attacker modifies his token because I verify thanks to firebase that the user is connected, if the local token changes, firebase will always say that the user is logged in but in my api the token will not be valid.

Comment: Answered below, based on an assumption that you're asking about a Firebase Authentication ID token, and a link to Android docs. In the future please provide more detailed information (such as the tag I added) and code of what you're doing (which also quite handily won't require translation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ID token you get from Firebase Authentication is an `exp` property/claim that shows you until when it's valid. Firebase's own SDKs refresh the token about 5 minutes before it expires, so your code should probably do the same. In fact, if you listen for when the ID token changes ([Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth#addIdTokenListener(com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.IdTokenListener)) [web](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.auth.Auth#onidtokenchanged)), you don't have to force a refresh yourself and can just piggyback on the work the SDK already does for you.

Comment: If the users are signing in client-side you should not have to generate a custom token for them. Can you edit your question to show more of the code? Code is better than words 99% of the time here, as we're all better at interpreting it (and it's much less ambiguous). Also see [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Don't post large updates in comments, and definitely not in an answer (it'll get deleted, as it's not an answer). Instead, edit your question to include the minimal-but-complete information needed. Instead of describing your implementation, I recommend showing us the [actual code that any of us can run to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That'll make it much more likely someone here can help you.

Comment: Do you understand better?

Comment: Thanks, that helps. The approach in my answer is still how to ensure you always have the right ID token, which is listening to `onIdTokenChanged`: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.auth.Auth#onidtokenchanged

Comment: For the moment I do not use it but I would like it because indeed I have problems because it can happen that my API receives expired tokens and that the user is still connected to my client.
What I was actually asking, is it better to use `onIdTokenChanged` and store it in localstorage or fetch the token for each request with `user.getIdToken` ?

Comment: There's no significant difference between the two, as `getIdToken` will also simply return the existing value from a local cache. Only if you force a refresh every time would there be a significant difference, but that's an anti-pattern (that we unfortunately see quite regularly).

Comment: ok thanks and i had one last question if you still have time

For users who log in in the classic way. What do you recommend for authenticating users to firebase ?